# ¿Como leer matrices de 2 dimensiones en Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Estoy aprendiendo a programar en ruby, ya sabia programar en c++ y con el uso de cin no hay problema pero en ruby he notado que el gets de ruby lee una linea completa de modo que si ingreso:

1 2 3 4

5 6 7 8

no puedo leer lo que viene despues del 1 o del 5 ¿Existe alguna funcion de lectura extra o hay que tomar el String completo que devuelve gets y recorrerlo para obtener los enteros

Answer (score 2):

El método `gets` lee una línea completa. Tendrás que extraer cada elemento de la línea leída y convertirlos en número.

En plan guarro:

```
gets.split.map {|x| x.to_i}
```

Comment: Funciono, gracias de antemano, revise el funcionamiento de 'split' y me sirvio para solucionar mi problema de lectura.

Answer (score 0):

Igualmente con [Matrix](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Matrix.html) puedes hacer operaciones con matrices

```
require 'matrix'  
m = Matrix[
 [1, 2, 3, 4],
 [5, 6, 7, 8]
]
```

Ya viene instalado con ruby solo es de importar la clase. Y ya cada vector los puedes ir usando como Arreglos normales.

Ejemplo:

```
m.minor(0..1, 2..2) 
# => Matrix[[3], [7]]

m.column 0
#=> Vector[1,5]

m.row 0
#=> Vector[1,2,3,4]
```